# Создание разных моделей таблицы JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Выполняю задание в университет, необходимо разработать GUI для моего проекта. Конкретно встала задача сделать отображение данных из трёх разных таблиц (Преподаватели, группы, нагрузка).

[image: Макет интерфейса]

Хотел добавить три разные `TableView` и по нажатию на соответствующий Menu в баре скрывать ненужные и отображать необходимую таблицу. Но где-то прочитал, что лучше сделать три разные модели таблицы и показывать необходимую. Но так и не смог понять, как сделать разные модели таблицы.`SceneBuilder` генерирует такой код:

```html
<TableView layoutX="108.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
 <columns>
   <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
   <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
 </columns>
</TableView>
```

Логически также не смог выяснить, как тут создать три разные модели. В добавок к этому справа будут кнопки "Редактировать запись", "Удалить", "Добавить".
 Нужно ли для них тоже делать различные версии кода или можно задать какой-то параметр каждой таблице, который будет передаваться контроллеру и тот будет сохранять изменённый результат в необходимую таблицу?
 Буду премного благодарен, если откроете мне глаза, дадите совет или хотя бы направите по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Scene Builder нужен для создания интерфейса, а вся логика должна быть описана в контроллере и модели.

Вот пример

```
@FXML
TableView table;


public void populateTable() {
    ObservableList<Record> records = getRecords();
    table.setItems(records);

    TableColumn<Record,String> firstCol = new TableColumn<Record,String>("First column");
    firstCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("col1"));
    TableColumn<Record,String> secondCol = new TableColumn<Record,String>("Second column");
    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("col2"));

    table.getColumns().setAll(firstCol, secondCol);

}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример, так и не смог понять, как правильно его использовать. Делаю как вы написали - в результате названия столбцов всё равно такие же, как делаю в Scene Builder, а не как написано в коде. Так и не понял схему разделения моделей одной таблицы

Comment: Вы не можете изменить generic тип объекта `TableView` - следовательно: либо извращаться и использовать тип `Object` с изменением списка столбцов таблицы, либо просто использовать отдельные `TableView` для каждого типа. Рекомендую второй вариант.